# Let $E$ and $F$ be Banach spaces and $T: E → F$ a function weakly Lipschitzian then $T$ is Lipschitzian

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lipschitz-functions, dual-spaces

Help me with this problem:

**Let $E$ and $F$ be Banach spaces and $T: E → F$ a function weakly
Lipschitzian (not necessarily linear), means that $f \circ T$ is a Lipschitz function for all $f \in F^*$, where $F^*$ it is the dual of $F$. Prove that $T$ is Lipschitzian**.

I tried the following:

If $f \circ T$ is a Lipschitz function, then $$\left| (f \circ T)(x)-(f \circ T)(y)\right|\leq K_f \left\|x-y \right\| \Rightarrow $$ 
$$\left| f (T(x)- T(y))\right|\leq K_f \left\| x-y \right\|$$

Take $f \neq0$.

Suppose that T is not Lipschitz, then  exist $(x_n), (y_n) \in E$ $\ $ such that
$$\left\|T(x_n)- T(y_n)\right\| > n \left\| x_n-y_n \right\| \ \forall \ n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Since $f$ is bounded, we have 
$$\left| f(T(x)- T(y))\right| \leq \left\| f \right\| \left\| T(x)- T(y) \right\|$$

Therefore
$$\left| f (T(x_n)- T(y_n))\right|\leq K_f \left\| x_n-y_n \right\| < \frac{K_f}{n} \left\|T(x_n)- T(y_n)\right\|$$ 
$\Rightarrow$ $\left\|f\right\|= \inf{\left\{C>0 \ ; \ |f(x)|\leq C\left\|x\right\|, x \in F   \right\}}< \frac{K_f}{n} \ \ \ \forall \ n \in \mathbb{N}$

Then $\left\|f\right\|=0 \Rightarrow f=0$, Contradiction, therefore $T$ is Lipschitzian.

Comment: The last but one line isn't correct: You know $|f(x)|\le a\|x\|$ only for very particular vectors $x=T(x_n)-T(y_n)$, but you would need it for all $x$.

Comment: Here's an idea: $\|T(x)-T(y)\|= \sup\{ |f(T(x)-T(y)|: \|f\|^*\le 1\}$. You would thus need a *uniform* estimate for the constants $K_f$. This cries for the uniform boundedness principle.

Answer (score 1):

The bound $K_f/n$ holds only for the sequence $v_n:=(T(x_n)-T(y_n))$ and not for all $x\in F$. This is why the argument does not hold.